# Rock paper scissors scoring problems

Tags: python

Please can someone tell me how to do a basic scoring system to go into this code.

```
import random
print 'Welcome to Rock, paper, scissors!'
firstto=raw_input('How many points do you want to play before it ends? ')

playerscore=+0
compscore=+0

while True:
    choice = raw_input ('Press R for rock, press P for paper or press S for scissors, CAPITALS!!! ')

    opponent = random.choice(['rock', 'paper' ,'scissors' ])

    print 'Computer has chosen', opponent

    if choice == 'R' and opponent == "rock":
        print 'Tie'
        playerscore = playerscore+0
        compscore = compscore+0

    elif choice == 'P' and opponent == "paper":
        print 'Tie'
        playerscore = playerscore+0
        compscore = compscore+0

    elif choice == 'S' and opponent == "scissors":
        print 'Tie'
        playerscore = playerscore+0
        compscore = compscore+0

    elif choice == 'R' and opponent == "paper":
        print 'CPU Wins'
        playerscore = playerscore+0
        compscore = compscore+1

    elif choice == 'P' and opponent == "scissors":
        print 'CPU Wins'
        playerscore = playerscore+0
        compscore = compscore+1

    elif choice == 'S' and opponent == "rock":
        print 'CPU Wins'
        playerscore = playerscore+0
        compscore = compscore+1


    elif choice == 'P' and opponent == "rock":
            print 'You Win'
            playerscore = playerscore+1 
            compscore = compscore+0

    elif choice == 'S' and opponent == "paper":
            print 'You Win'
            playerscore = playerscore+1
            compscore = compscore+0

    elif choice == 'R' and opponent == "scissors":
            print 'You Win'
            playerscore = playerscore+1
            compscore = compscore+0


    print 'Player score is',playerscore
    print 'Computer score is',compscore

    if playerscore == firstto:
        'You won the game :)'
        exit()
    elif compscore == firstto:
        'You lost the game :('
        exit()
```

Comment: Looks like you already have a scoring system there. What exactly is your issue? Is the code not working, and if so what do you see?

Comment: The game wont end when the player score or computer score is reached

Comment: Please edit your question to include relevant information like that.

Comment: You forgot [Lizard and Spock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock-paper-scissors-lizard-Spock). (SCNR)

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies with `raw_input` on line 3. `raw_input` always returns a string, whereas what you need is an int. If you change line 3 to:

```
firstto = int(raw_input('How many points do you want to play before it ends? '))
```

your code will work.

To sanitize user input (so that your code does not come crashing down when the user enters `"hello"` instead of `5`), you can wrap the `raw_input` call into a `try`, `except` statement.

For instance:

```
valid_input = False # flag to keep track of whether the user's input is valid.
while not valid_input:
    firstto_str = raw_input('How many points do you want to play before it ends? ')
    try:
        # try converting user input to integer
        firstto = int(firstto_str)
        valid_input = True
    except ValueError:
        # user input that cannot be coerced to an int -> raises ValueError.
        print "Invalid input, please enter an integer."
```

---

As an aside, your code was stuck in an infinite loop because you were using the string provided by `raw_input` in comparisons with integers. This will always return False:

```
>>> "5" == 5
False
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to optimize this code, but your immediate problem is the `raw_input` and the entry of points. This returns a string, while you need an `int`. Wrap it with `int()` and you'll be fine. That is, until someone enters a something that cannot be parsed.

```
firstto = int(raw_input('How many points do you want to play before it ends? '))
```

---

**EDIT**: If you're interested, I've tried optimizing your code a bit (without going to extremes):

```
import random

what_beats_what = [('R', 'S'), ('S', 'P'), ('P', 'R')]
choices = {'R': 'Rock', 'P': 'Paper', 'S': 'Scissors'}


def outcome(player_a, player_b):
    for scenario in what_beats_what:
        if player_a == scenario[0] and player_b == scenario[1]:
            return 'A'
        elif player_b == scenario[0] and player_a == scenario[1]:
            return 'B'


print 'Welcome to Rock, paper, scissors!'

score_to_win = 0

while True:
    try:
        score_to_win = int(raw_input('How many points do you want to play before it ends? '))
        if score_to_win > 0:
            break
    except ValueError:
        pass

    print 'Try again, with a positive integer.'

human_score = 0
cpu_score = 0

while human_score < score_to_win and cpu_score < score_to_win:
    human_choice = ''
    while True:
        human_choice = raw_input('Press R for rock, press P for paper or press S for scissors: ').upper()
        if human_choice in choices:
            break
        else:
            print 'Try again ...'

    cpu_choice = random.choice(choices.keys())
    print 'Computer has chosen: {0}'.format(choices[cpu_choice])

    result = outcome(human_choice, cpu_choice)

    if result == 'A':
        print "Human wins!"
        human_score += 1
    elif result == 'B':
        print "CPU wins!"
        cpu_score += 1
    else:
        print 'It is a tie!'

    print 'Human score is: {0}'.format(human_score)
    print 'CPU score is: {0}'.format(cpu_score)

print 'You won the game :)' if human_score > cpu_score else 'You lost the game :('
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your first raw_input value. You are getting a string there.

For better result, validate the input as well :-)

```
while 1:
    firstto=raw_input('How many points do you want to play before it ends? ')
    if firstto.isdigit():
        firstto = int(firstto)
        break
    else:
        print "Invalid Input. Please try again"
```

This will accept only the strings with numbers. Even if some one gives input as "5.0", it will be neglected.

For better reading on raw_input, click [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input). To learn more about built-in string methods, read [here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.5/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).

PS: This is not related to the question. But a little suggestion. Your code could be made much simpler. If you are learning, keep this code as v0.1 and update it upon your progress.

Comment: Your link for string methods refers to the documentation of python 2.5 (released in 2006). You might want to change it to something a bit more up-to-date...

Comment: Good catch :) Will update now :)